# ReplaceAll is not working

Tags: java, regex

I have following code

```
String s = "A'BDG";

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("'", "\\'"));
```

So output is same as String s and it is not replacing `'` with `\'`. However it is working fine with `replace()`, so whats the problem with `replaceAll()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) if you are dealing with literal strings:

```
s.replace("'", "\\'")
```

It will replace all instances of `'` in the string with `\'`.

---

The [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`String.replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) functions works with [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (regex).

Though there is no problem with `"'"` being the pattern, the replacement string `"\\'"` is the source of your problem. Since the replacement string can contain special sequences such as `$1` to refer to text captured by capturing group, the syntax must allow plain `$` to be specified by escaping `\\$`. This escaping will cause `\'` to be interpreted as `'` in the replacement string syntax.

This is why you need to double up the escaping `"\\\\'"` for the replacement string to work correctly. One layer of escaping to give `\\'` to the `replaceAll`/`replaceFirst` function, the next layer to make the replacement string being interpreted as `\'`.

```
s.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")
```

In such case, [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) can be used to quote the replacement string when you want to replace with fixed string:

```
s.replaceAll("'", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\'"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
String s = "A'BDG"; 
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\'", "\\\\'"));
```

You have to escape `'` by `\\` with `replaceAll()`

Out put:

```
A\'BDG
```

Comment: Searching can be done with `"'"`, the problem here is with the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using replace function it identifies the escape symbols differently and add another \\ and call the  replaceAll method with correct way.
if you do

```
s.replace("'", "\\'")
```

it will automatically call

```
s.replaceAll("\\'", "\\\\'")
```

But if you call replaceAll function directly It doesn`t have any clue to identify special charactors like ' \ by its own. If you go into replace function you will see that additional \ will be added to this escape characters by quoteReplacement method in replaceall function .

so if you want to use replace all function use it withy extra escape charactors like

```
s.replaceAll("\\'", "\\\\'")
```

cheers